# Nodejs counter cache or sharding?

Tags: node.js, caching

In my NodeJS application, i have one database update which increments `visit_count` on every request to my API. It was working good until now. Now, i have significantly more traffic and more DB updates. So to want to implement some kind of counter cache to prevent my app from sending update to MongoDB on every increment operation on  `visit_count`. I Googled a lot but never found anything like "counter cache for NodeJS".

I talked to friend and he suggested me to use HashMap for managing counter cache ( in memory ). I don't know much about counter cache. How they will be flushed to MongoDB and on what basis ?

I also used LRU cache by Isaac for counters. But i lost some counters ( Now i know why ).

I am using Mongoose and MongoDB.

**Current rate** is 24,550 increments per second.

Comment: how much is "significantly more traffic"?  whats the message rate?  On the other hand, if the database truly is your bottleneck (which i doubt), you could simply keep your counter in memory and write every 100th or 1000th time

Comment: @alernerde, added update rate.

Comment: I would keep it as simple as possible - lets say you keep an in memory count of how many times you wrote to the HashMap -- and you flush it out every % 10 to MongoDB (by doing a MongoDB update). Its good enough for now, but if one day you scale out to shards and multiple load balanced mongos, you will have to rethink it -- you cant shard a single value, right? So no matter how many connections and shards you have, you will still need to update just a single document record.  You will cross that bridge when you come to it.  for now, keep it simple.

Comment: I concur with the above comment, just make a counter variable in your code and commit to Mongo every x requests.